# Howe to count an event by minute in Big Query

Tags: time, google-bigquery, utc

Many years ago I knew SQL quite well but apparently it's been so long I lost my skills and knolwedge.

I have a number of tables that each track a given event with additional metadata. One piece of Metadata is a timestamp in UTC format(2021-08-11 17:27:27.916007 UTC).

Now I need to count how many times the event occurred per minute.
Col 1, Col2
EventName, Timestamp in UTC

I am trying to recall my past knowledge and also how to apply that to BQ.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding well, you could transform your Timestamp into `minutes` and then group by it.

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS number_events, 
       FLOOR(UNIX_SECONDS(your_timestamp)/60) AS minute 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_SECONDS(your_timestamp)/60)
```

So it transforms your timestamps to `unix_seconds`, then divide by 60 to get minutes and `floor()` to skip decimals after the division.

If you have multiple type of events in the same table, just add the name of the event to the `select` and to the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to group by event column.
Then the Timestamp events can be counted.

```
Select Col2_EventName, count(Timestamp )
group by 1
```

Depending on your data, some more transformation have to be done. E.g. ignore the seconds in the timestamp and hold only the full minutes, as done in the answer from Javier Montón.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.